How can I properly generalize form inputs in Laravel Volt?
I'm coming from a React and WordPress development background and trying to wrap my head around Livewire components using Laravel Volt. My dilemma is that I'm trying to generalize more form components, but I'm running into difficulties with keeping the state synchronized.
Here is my form component:
<?php

use App\Models\MyModel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Livewire\Volt\Component;

new class extends Component {

    #[Validate('required|string|max:256')]
    public string $description;

    public ?MyModel $editing = null;

    public function submit(): void
    {
        $validated = $this->validate();
        $this->dispatch('my-model-form-submitted', $validated);
        $this->description = '';
    }

    public function mount(): void
    {
        if (isset($editing)) {
            $this->editing = $editing;
            $this->description = $this->editing->description;
        } else {
            $this->description = '';
        }
    }
};

?>

<form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
    <livewire:form-input :label="__('Description')" id="description" wire:model="description"
        placeholder="{{ __('Describe the thing') }}" :error="$errors->get('description')" />
    <livewire:form-input :label="__('Description a second time')" id="description2" wire:model="description"
        placeholder="{{ __('Ideally in sync with the same value as the first input') }}" :error="$errors->get('description')" />
    <div>
        {{ $editing }}
        <x-primary-button>{{ $editing ? __('Update') : __('Save') }}</x-primary-button>
    </div>
</form>

Here is the views/livewire/form-input.blade.php component (basically the input with label and error message):
<?php

use Livewire\Attributes\Modelable;

new class extends \Livewire\Volt\Component {
    public string $id;
    public string $label;

    #[Modelable]
    public string $value = '';

    public string $placeholder;
    public array $error;

    public function mount(string $id, string $label, string $placeholder, array $error = []): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->label = $label;

        $this->placeholder = $placeholder;
        $this->error = $error;
    }
};

?>

<x-form-group>
    <x-input-label for="{{ $id }}">{{ $label }}</x-input-label>
    <x-input-text type="{{ $type ?? 'text' }}" id="{{ $id }}" wire:model="value"
        placeholder="{{ $placeholder }}" />
    <x-input-error :messages="$error" />
</x-form-group>

and here is views/components/input-text.blade.php (Just the input element):
<input
    {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => ' class="block w-full px-4 py-2 border-gray-300 text-slate-900 dark:text-white focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"']) }}>

I feel like I'm missing a key detail since the two inputs in the form aren't staying in sync, loading a model for editing isn't setting the value of the inputs, and submitting the form only disables it, without dispatching the event or resetting the value of description.
Update:
I did figure out the two input staying in sync dilemma. I see now that the state is only updated with the server when an action is performed. https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/wire-model but I'm still puzzled about the loading for edit and missing values at time of submission.

First, let's take a look at your mount function
 public function mount(): void
    {
        if (isset($editing)) {

We're checking to see if the $editing variable is set, but we're never attempting to set it. You can do this by specifying that it's a parameter we accept in the mount function.
Below is a fixed version, I've renamed MyModel to a Post model just so it makes more sense.
public function mount(?Post $post = null): void
    {
        if (isset($post)) {
            $this->post = $post;

The mount method isn't the constructor of the class, but that's essentially how it behaves. That may be a concept your familiar with coming from react.
This is not yet a complete solution.
Further Improvements
Now to finish it off, we're going to do things the 'laravel way' as well as some security related concerns we should be aware of and a better way to do things for perfomance.
    #[Validate('required|string|min:1|max:256')]
    public string $description;

    public Post $post;

    public function submit(): void
    {
        $validated = $this->validate();
        /** 
        * You likely just gave me psuedo but we should actually create a 
        * model here usually */
        $this->dispatch('my-post-form-submitted', $validated);
        $this->description = '';
    }

    public function mount(?Post $post = null): void
    {
        if (isset($post)) {
            $this->post = $post;
            $this->description = $this->post->description;
        }
    }

Previously our mount function would set the description variable to have a value of an empty string. Because it was initialised it would always pass the 'required' validation rule.
We can also set Post to null in the mount method. Using ?Post $post = null we've specified that the $post parameter should be an instance of the Post class. We've also given it a default value of null which will be used if no Post was passed when rendering the component.
To double down on ensuring the user has entered something as the description a min validation rule has been set, specifying atleast 1 character.
The mount function has a $post parameter that is typehinted. If this form has a route and it's a full page component this is how it would be done. If this form is just a child component and has a parent you should change this to accept an integer and load the related model with a line similar to this inside the mount method.
$this->post = Post::findOrFail($id);

I don't have full implementation details and only what has been provided, but the context I've got is giving me the impression that the parent component has a copy of the Post model and it's being used vertically.
It doesn't make sense to do this in most scenarios. If the parent needs an instance of the Post, un-nest this component and just place the functionality in its parent. Passing models vertically through nested components is quite messy.
Security Concerns
Livewire will include any public properties in requests to keep track of state. This can be dangerous in some circumstances as the user can modify the values of properties with the public access modifier.
For instance if a user is editing a post and they're only supposed to edit posts that belong to them, they could manipulate the postId property if you stored it in a public property to edit a post that wasn't theirs.
Luckily Livewire is smart and locks the ID property for us on models. But do bare this in mind in future and take a look at Property Security Concerns
Handling Form Submission
Inside your form you look to be emitting the property $description which suggests it's being passed vertically between components.
This is really not performant and is dangerous as this is all done client side and the user can manipulate the properties and their values.
If you need to pass these parameter vertically because it's wanting to have seperation of concerns I understand. If that's the case you can leverage Livewire Forms as they don't have a view and they just contain the validation and submission logic of the form.
State & Live Updating
You can configure the state so that's its practically checked as soon as a user enters a key inside one of the inputs that has a binding to a property. There are ton of different options but I recommend using wire:model.onblur as it will only fire a request when the input loses focus which will ensure our application isn't being too loud and sending more data than we need to.
One last note but I won't go into too much detail. The input components don't have to be Livewire components and you can just use Blade Components for what you're currently trying to achieve from them. Livewire is just heavy handed for your current requirements.

Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Is there any good general resources for Volt and Livewire outside of the Laravel docs? I'm still trying to sort out the "what happens on the server" vs "what happens on the client"

Personally I don't use Volt for this exact reason.
I use Livewire without Volt so that I have one file which is the blade file / IE what the client can see and the Livewire Component class which is the server side logic.
